# Sort icon(up down arrows) on searchable columns of datatables is not displaying

Tags: jquery, html, datatable

I have a jquery datatable, in which some of the columns are made searchable

```
var oTable = $('#genericTable').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": '<%=jsonPath%>' + key + ".json",
        "sPaginationType"   : "full_numbers",
        "bJQueryUI"         : true,
        "bRetrieve"         : true,
        "bPaginate"         : true,
        "bSort"             : true,
        "aaSorting"  : [[ 2, "desc" ]],
        "iDisplayLength"    : 50,
        "bAutoWidth"        : false,
        "aoColumns": [
                      { "sTitle": "Name", sWidth: '200px' },
                      { "sTitle": "Description", sWidth: '360px' },
                      { "sTitle": "Date", sWidth: '70px', "sType": 'date-uk' },
                      { "sTitle": "Action", sWidth: '60px', "bSortable": false }
                    ],

    }).columnFilter({ sPlaceHolder: "head:after",
        aoColumns: [ { type: "text" },
                     { type: "text" },
                     null,
                     null
                   ]
    }); 

    } );
});
```

The columns which are searchable (textbox displaying in header to search) does not have updown arrow icon right to textbox, while other column header have this sort icon

May i know What can be the solution to display sort icon next to textbox in column header??

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. The way I fixed it was removing the sScrollY property. If you leave bPaginate on, you should get properly sized tables.
EDIT: I misspoke. You need to have scroll on, and turn paginate off. They sort of work mutually exclusively.